# Beer cocktail recommendation

Tags: recommendations, beer-cocktails, vodka

I do not have much options in beer variety and therefore I need some good cocktail of beer with vodka/tequila or some other good choice to make it good for a party.

Is there any way to mix things up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing vodka with beer?](http://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/mixing-vodka-with-beer)

Comment: Well I experiment quite a lot with different beers, either mixing up two or three different ones to see how well they taste together or mixing a beer with a spirit. Having worked in a number of different beer bars I am exposed to beers of all kinds more often than not. I'd say try using sour beers and experiment with the liquors that you have at home to see what you feel tastes best. Sweet beers might work as well.

Comment: Try different Bourbons and beer (preferably porters/stouts). My favorite currently is Dragon's milk + Crown Royal. The sweetness of dark beers lends to blending with Bourbons, hence the "Bourbon Barrel Aged XYZ" beers you see. Note: I've ruined good beers and wasted good bourbon trying this.

Comment: My brother used to drink Diesel (half lager,half cider and shot of blackcurrant) and add shot of Pernod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few fairly popular (and very different) beer cocktails are:

- The Boilermaker or Depth Charge
  The original English version was a mix of draught and brown, but it's more recently been popularised in Australia and the USA as a pint of beer with a shot of spirit (usually whisk[e]y) in it. If the shot is poured in, it's a Boilermaker. If the entire shot glass is dropped into the pint glass, it's a Depth Charge. Take care as this can make you very drunk more quickly than you expect (some may consider this a feature, but I'm trying to post responsible advice here).
  Useful when: you want to make your beer (or your spirits) more interesting.
- The Black Velvet
  Equal parts stout and champagne served inna champagne flute. The stout is floated on top for a striking visual effect.
  Useful when: you want to add some class to your beering.
- The Michelada
  Lager spiced up with lime juice, salt and hot sauce. There are many variations, some including things like clam juice, tomato juice, worcestershire sauce or chilli flakes. It's kind of like a Bloody Mary in beer form.
  Useful when: you want to treat a hangover.
- The Shandy
  Equal parts beer and a softer drink, usually lemonade.
  Useful when: you don't really like beer or lemonade but there's not much else on offer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some beer cocktails:

**The Bulldog Mexicana**

The Mexican Bulldog Margarita, simply put, is a margarita joined by a bottle of Corona--in the same glass. Specifically, that glass should be large enough to handle a margarita and a beer. To make this specialty, all that's needed is one ounce of your favorite tequila (if you add an extra splash, we won't tell). You'll also need lime margarita mix and any other margarita fixings you like such as salt around the rim and a juicy slice of lime. Mix up your margarita as you normally would. When it's complete, you will invert the bottle of Corona into the glass allowing the golden beer to combine with the cocktail. The result is quite extraordinary. Many people love the way the beer cuts down on some of the cocktail's sweetness. Others simply love the punch it packs. Because this drink is actually two drinks combined in one glass, you may want to take it easy on ordering a second or add some crushed ice to the glass!

**Keep It Classic: The Black Velvet**

Featuring one-part Guinness and one-part brut sparkling wine, the Black Velvet is a London-born beer cocktail that first wowed pub goers in 1861. The drink was actually created to help mourn the loss of Queen Victoria's consort, Prince Albert. Champagne is traditionally the sparkling wine of choice but others may be substituted. Serve this half and half beverage in a stout beer glass and you may then enjoy its Victorian charms.

**Keep it Light: the Cuban Bul**

If you're not in the mood for the heavy Black Velvet, try the refreshing spritzer-like Cuban Bul. You'll need a 12-oz can of light beer (choose something crisp), a 12 oz can of ginger ale, two tablespoons of sugar (or to taste), and a third of a cup of lime juice (go for freshly squeezed). Mix the ingredients along with some crushed ice in a glass, taste, and discover your new favorite cocktail; it's a winner and you'll be amazed at how light and delicious it tastes!

[Beer + Cocktails: Why Choose One When You Can Have Them Together!](https://www.zindeed.com/articles/beer-cocktails-why-choose-one-when-you-can-have-them-together)

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, I never came across a "beer cocktail", certainly not one spiked with strong spirits (hard liquor in AmE) like vodka or tequila. I'm somewhat *surprised* (British understatement) that the OP needs to do this to a good glass of beer in order to "make it a good party" [sic]. Doing this is just as likely to ruin the enjoyment of the vodka/tequila and vice-versa the beer. Such adulteration of these two mutually exclusive beverages is an abomination. Evidently the hoped for effect of spiking beer in this way is to encourage inebriation among the party goers. Not the sort of thing that makes a "good party" in my experience. Beer "cocktails" of a more benign kind in the UK also include a "shandy", traditional beer to which non-alcoholic fizzy lemonade is added. In the UK, another beer cocktail of sorts is the "Black & Tan", a fifty-fifty mixture of traditional beer or pale ale with dark porter or stout (typically Guinness)  I think the Scots got it right when they embraced the "beer-chaser", a pint of traditional beer ordered with a wee dram of Scotch (whiskey) on the side, served separately in a glass tot. A beer "cocktail" of this kind, drunk in tandem with each other, is so much more appealing than throwing hard liquor in with a good beer and vice versa.

Comment: In the UK, during the 1970's & 80's, consumption and domination of traditional beer was dented by the slow but inexorable rise in popularity of lager. It became fashionable, particularly among the ladies, to drink a lager & lime (cordial), a quasi-beer cocktail. The men followed suit to a certain extent if only because the middling quality of lager available in this era benefited from a good dash of lime cordial. The popularity of a lager & lime has waned but the consumption of straight lager has burgeoned in the last 30 years, quite possibly matching or overtaking that of beer in the UK.

Comment: In support of my claim that lager consumption has matched or overtaken traditional beer in UK sales, I cite The Daily Telegraph, "How the UK became a nation of lager drinkers", online edition, 28 Nov 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly beer, but a Spiked Apple Cider (like Redd's, Angry Orchard, or Bold Rock) mixed with a shot of Fireball Cinnamon Whiskey is delicious.  As an added bonus, neither of the ingredients are particularly potent, as such, most people can have 1 or 2 and not be completely hammered.

This drink is sometimes called Angry Balls, Apple Beer Bomb, Double Spiked Cider, Redd Balls, or a Dicken's Cider.  It works as a drop shot or a cocktail and unlike most other beer cocktails the ingredients create a proper flavor fusion.  While delicious year 'round. This cocktail has a distinct autumn appeal.

In a drink that may appear offensive to some, Guinness(other stouts work too) mixes well with ice cream, for a beer milkshake or beer float.  Throw in Bailey's, Kahlua, and/or Vodka with the beer and vanilla ice cream to make an Irish Mudslide.  The combination of Guinness with ice cream creates a sort of malted flavor.  Without other liquors, a Guinness shake is not particularly strong and this suits itself well to a dessert drink.

Finally, a fairly popular drink using non alcoholic ginger beer would be a Moscow Mule.  Vodka + non alcoholic Ginger Beer + lime juice.
This works well with an Alcoholic Ginger Beer like Crabbie's, but be mindful that a glass of crabbies with a shot of vodka is roughly equivalent to drinking two glasses of beer.  Replacing Vodka with lower proofed alcohol like Lemoncello or even flavored vodkas(like Whipped Vodka - kinda like a cream soda with ginger beer) can allow for people to have multiples of these.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering this thread, I wanted to jump myself back to [a pub in my town](https://goo.gl/maps/xVT12cDNfCFW9x528) where they offer a selection of Guinness and beer cocktails, take a photo to the menu and ask a few things to the owner.

[image: photo of the menu]

The image above does of course not represent any standard, and an Irish pub in a foreigner country may not be 100% traditional, but it shows a variety of blends of beers with other drinks.

To resume, **Guinness draught** is mixed with:

- stronger drinks (1/3 vodka or 1/3 blue curaçao or 1/3 Prosecco);
- beer-like drinks (1/3 cider or 1/2 Kilkenny or 1/3 other beer);
- soft drinks (tonic water or orange juice).

Also in the list: 1/2 **Harp** + 1/2 cider + grenadine.

None of the above Guinness cocktails is supposed to result layered.